# Probability of Two Independent Events Occuring after $n$ trials

Tags: probability

We have two independent events, event A which occurs with $p=1/9$ and event B which occurs with $p=1/15$ (and can only happen after event A has already happened). What is the probability that after $n$ trials both $A$ and $B$ have occurred at least once given that event $B$ can only happen after event $A$?

Comment: How can they be independent if $B$ can not occur before $A$?

Comment: What does "can only occur after $A$ occured" mean ? Speaking of "after $n$ trials" is a nice intuitive way of seeing things but does not reflect anything in the "maths world"

Comment: Well, I guess not no. That was somewhat stupid of me.

Comment: It means A occurs with probability 1/9 and once A does occur then B has probability 1/15.

Comment: So...letting $X$ denote the complement of $A\cup B$, we have that prior to the first occurrence of $A$, $p_A=\frac 19$ and $p_X=\frac 89$ and after the first occurrence of $A$ we have $p_A=\frac 19, p_B=\frac 1{15},p_X=\frac {37}{45}$?

Comment: Yeah, that is what I mean. Very sorry. And yes by $n$ trials I mean n events. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

there are two cases.

Case I:  $A$ never occurs.  The probability of that is $\left(\frac 89\right)^n$

Case II:  $A$ occurs but $B$ does not.  That one is trickier.  We need to consider the various places $A$ might have occurred first. Let $i\in \{1,n\}$ denote the first occurrence of $A$ and let $P_i$ denote the probability that $B$ does not occur at all, given that the first occurrence of $A$ is in slot  $i$.  Then $$P_i=\left( \frac 89\right)^{i-1}\times \frac 19\times \left(\frac {14}{15}\right)^{n-i}$$  The probability of Case II occuring is then $$\sum_{i=1}^nP_i= \left(\frac 52\right)^{1 - n} \,3^{-2 n}\, (21^n- 20^n) $$

Here I have included the closed formula more as a curiosity than any thing else. (Full disclosure:  I let Wolfram Alpha compute the sum, which may account for it's somewhat odd presentation.  It is really just a geometric series with some multiplicative factors tossed in.)

Comment: How did you change the equation into a closed form? You say you used Wolfram-Alpha, what program did you use?

Comment: @JohnSmith  Well I just typed "Sum[(8/9)^(i - 1) (1/9) (14/15)^(n - i), {i, 1, n}]" Though when I do that know I get a different result, so perhaps I mistyped it before or perhaps the two forms are equivalent.  Now it is telling me  "5/2 9^(-n) ((42/5)^n - 8^n)".  I will look into it later.